# Karma with Grails2.4+asset pipeline. Any way to avoid duplicating JS includes?

Tags: javascript, grails, karma-runner

I upgraded an app from Grails2.3+resources to Grails2.4+asset pipeline. In both environments my karma.conf.js has a hand-built list of javascript includes- many being order-dependent. Now I have the same list in `//= require` pragmas in my javascript app.

This duplication seems problematic. Is there an elegant way to share the required includes?